# Automatically collect data from multiple webpages for excel

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I've been trying to automate a task but recently came to an issue. Part of the task is to copy and paste 2 pieces of information from a website into the excel document.

Here is some examples of what the webpages looks like:

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-0253

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-0300

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-0256

The data that I wish to collect is the "Current Description" and the value for "CVSS v3.0 Base score"

There is always multiple links which I have to take the data from but they are all very similar, the only difference being what CVE-****-**** it is.

Currently I have it so that excel puts the actual links to the webpages into a list.

Is there a way that I can create a macro which automatically goes through the list of links and takes the "Current Description" and "CVSS v3.0 Base Score" data from the websites and puts them into cells in excel.

Thank you for any help / suggestions / tips.

Comment: Please include your code with the question between code tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it. Obviously you can tweak how you handle missing information. I am just giving an example using the CVEs provided. You really should provide your efforts as I have no idea what approach you are using.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/"
    Dim i As Long, CVES(), tempArr()
    CVES = Array("CVE-2018-0253", "CVE-2018-0300", "CVE-2018-0256")
    For i = LBound(CVES) To UBound(CVES)
        tempArr = GetDescriptionAndScore(BASE_URL & CVES(i))
        Debug.Print "Desc: " & tempArr(0)
        Debug.Print "Score: " & tempArr(1)
        Erase tempArr
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetDescriptionAndScore(ByVal url As String) As Variant
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, arr(1), sResponse As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        arr(0) = .querySelector("[data-testid=vuln-description]").innerText
        If InStr(1, sResponse, "This vulnerability is currently awaiting analysis") > 0 Then
            arr(1) = "Not available"
        Else
            arr(1) = .querySelector("[data-testid=vuln-cvssv3-base-score]").innerText
        End If
    End With
    GetDescriptionAndScore = arr
End Function
```

---

**References (via VBE> Tools > References):**

HTML Object Library

Comment: Did you try this?